# How to match multiple words(per string) in array with a string containing multiple words

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x, match

**This has been resolved. See bottom of this post for a solution**

I'm trying to filter out a continuous loop that has a constant feed of strings coming in(from an API).

Heres an example of the code I'm using -

I have a filter set up with an array like so:

```
filter_a = ['apples and oranges', 'a test', 'bananas']
```

a function I found on Stackoverflow like this:

```
def words_in_string(word_list, a_string):
    return set(word_list).intersection(a_string.split())
title = 'bananas'
#(this is a continuously looping thing, so sometimes it 
# might be for example 'apples and oranges')
```

And my if statement:

```
if words_in_string(filter_a, str(title.lower())):
    print(title.lower())
```

For some reason it would detect 'bananas' but not 'apples and oranges'. It will skip right over strings with multiple words. I'm guessing it's because of the split() but I'm not sure.

**Edit:**
Here's another example of what I meant:

Match this and make it successful:

```
title = 'this is 1'

word_list = ['this is','a test']

if title in word_list:
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccessful")
```

**Edit 2:**

### Solution

title = 'this is 1'

word_list = ['this is','a test']

if any(item in title for item in word_list):
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccessful")

Comment: we need a simple example, show us what `word_list` and `a_string` would be?

Comment: Yes, it is because of the split. It looks like you will need to use a loop and go through each phrase with a `word in sentence` sort of logic, which is inefficient.

Comment: modified it a bit hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: Yeah the whole thing is already a loop so if I can avoid having to run a loop inside of that, that would be a lot better. Just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code makes sense. Let's analyze what does `words_in_string` do.

`word_list` means a list of words you want to keep, and `set(word_list)` transform this list into a set which only contains unique elements. In your example, transform `['apples and oranges', 'a test', 'bannanas']` into a set is `{'apples and oranges', 'a test', 'bannanas'}`.

Next, `a_string.split()` splits `a_string` into a list, then call `set`'s function `intersection` to get the intersection of set and what `a_string.split()` created.

Finally, return the result.

To be more clearly, given a list of words, this function will return the words in `a_string` if these words are also contained in list.

For example:

given `["banana", "apple", "orange"]` and `a_string = "I like banana and apple"`. It will return `{"banana", "apple"}`.

But if you change list into `["bananas", "apple", "orange"]`, it will only return `{"apple"}` as `banana` doesn't equal to `bananas`.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do

Comment: @Jonathan Until now, `split` changes `apples and oranges` into `["apples", "and", "oranges"]`. So these are three words but not *a word*.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. I'm trying to figure out how to make it work. :/

Comment: For example, trying to make this print successful. Even if it only matches part.
`title = 'this is 1'

word_list = ['this is','a test']

if title in word_list:
    print("successful")
else:
    print("unsuccessful")`

Comment: @Jonathan If you don't mind performance. You can use `return [item for item in word_list if item in a_string]`

Comment: I got some help from Reddit. I genuinely appreciate you trying to help though. I edited my post above to include the solution.